# Counting character in string

Tags: c, comparison

This code's purpose is counting how many times the inputed character is used in inputed string.

Code is like this it gives **false output K=41 And Warning Comparison always false due to limited range of data type.**

```
int main()
{
    int i,k,x=0;
    char ch;
    char str[1000];
    printf("Write your Word!\n");
    gets(str);
    printf("Write character to Search\n");
    scanf("%c",&ch);
    x=strlen(str);
    printf("%d",x);
    printf("%d",k);
          for(i=0;i!=x-1;i++){
             if(str[i]=='ch'){

              k++; }           
              }           
     printf("%d times used",k);
     getch();

 return 0;


    }
```

Comment: `k` is not initialised

Comment: The comparison warning is because of `str[i]=='ch'`; `str[i]` is one character, you're *comparing with 2 characters*.

Comment: What did u mean by not initialised? Where should i initiate k?In if loop?

Comment: Initialize `k` in your declaration: `int i,k=0,x=0;`

Comment: @AlterMann initialized k like u said but it still gives 0.Why?

Comment: @user1944312 did you ever used **a debugger**?

Comment: @Drop No i am realy new dont know how to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some issues: you did not initialise `k` and the comparison should be with variable `ch`, not   constant `'ch'`. This should work (notice I also changed your `printf`s for cleaner output):

```
int main() 
{
    int i,k=0,x=0;
    char ch;
    char str[1000];
    printf("Write your Word!\n");
    gets(str);
    printf("Write character to Search\n");
    scanf("%c",&ch);
    x=strlen(str);
    printf("strlen = %d\n",x);
    for(i=0;i!=x-1;i++){
        if(str[i]==ch){
            k++; }             
        }                 
     printf("%d times used\n",k);
     getch();
     return 0;

}
```

Comment: `'ch'` is not a string (that would be `"ch"`); it is a multi-character `int` constant.

Comment: To be perfect, `gets()` shouldn't be there. It doesn't hurt to use `fgets()` instead. `gets()` is old, it stinks, and should **never** be used. It was even removed from C11.

Comment: OK Thank you so much couldn't find like an half hour.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves I am new to writing what is the difference why gets() stinks?

Comment: @user1944312 Because it doesn't know your buffer size, thus, it can overflow. In other words, if the user enters more data than your buffer can hold, `gets()` will happily write past the limit. `fgets()` receives the size of the buffer, so it will stop if there is no space left. In your code, it's as simple as replacing `gets(str)` by `fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin)`. This is a substantial improvement.